# Excel Online Freezes when inserting add-in in test environment

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, ms-wopi

Update 11/12/17: It looks like the issue has been resolved. Excel Online does not freeze and works normally when inserting an add-in.

On 21/11/17 I lost the ability to side load my add-in in the Excel Online test environment. The application is WOPI integrated. Did anything change? Excel Online and the browser tab now freeze completely when I try to load my add-in from the manifest. This has rendered us unable to test changes to our add-in locally.

I'm not sure what information to provide. The Excel Online build id is: 16.0.8821.2656.

Update: This is actually happening with add-ins inserted through the store as well, so it isn't just sideloading our local add-in. I can go to the store and add Script Lab and Excel Online will freeze.

Comment: To make sure it's not a problem with your code, could you make a version of your add-in that points to a public SSL site like https://www.bing.com and then share your manifest?

Comment: @MichaelSaunders Thanks for responding. this is actually happening with any add-in. I tried adding Script Lab from the store and Excel Online freezes just the same.

I'll update my question.

Comment: It's looks like the issue has been resolved. Excel Online is no longer freezing when I insert an add-in.